# Python: Selecting files from a directory with a given list of names

Tags: python, string, filter, move, readfile

Basically, I need to pick some files from a directory based on their names and move them to somewhere else.

So, I have a list of names of the files which I need to do the following:

**1)Read the .txt file line by line**

**2)Compare the strings in the list to the file names/paths of a given directory**

**3)Move the ones that match to a new directory.**

```
List_1

Out:
['/path_to_the_files/OG0000005.fa',
 '/path_to_the_files/OG0000010.fa',
 '/path_to_the_files/OG0000015.fa',
 '/path_to_the_files/OG0000020.fa',
 '/path_to_the_files/OG0000025.fa',
 '/path_to_the_files/OG0000030.fa']

List_2

Out:
['OG0000010.fa',
 'OG0000020.fa',
 'OG0000030.fa']
```

```
import re 
import shutil

def filter_list(string, substr): 
    return [st for st in string if any(sub in st for sub in substr)] 



#List_1, files in a given directory 
list_1=glob.glob('/path_to_the_files/*.fa')

#List_2, files that need to be picked
file = open("/path_to_name_list/list_2.txt", "r")
file_lines = file.read()
list_2 = file_lines.split("\n") 


filtered_list=filter_list(list_2,list_1)


shutil.("old_path_to_the_filtered_list",
           "new_path_to_the_filtered_list")
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: can u give an example of the list_2.txt

Comment: The question was how do you make the script work properly but no worries I get the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is your list after reading list_2.txt

```
['OG0000010.fa',
 'OG0000020.fa',
 'OG0000030.fa']
```

Then you can cycle through the directory where the files are located, and move them to the new directory if your file is in the list,

```
import shutil
import os

file = open("/path_to_name_list/list_2.txt", "r")
file_lines = file.read()
list_2 = file_lines.split("\n") # ['OG0000010.fa','OG0000020.fa','OG0000030.fa']


directory = 'path/to/file/'
new_directory = 'path/to/new/dir'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename in list_2:
        old_loc = rf"{directory}/{filename}"
        new_loc = rf"{new_directory}/{filename}"
        shutil.move(old_loc, new_loc)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you very much of your help!

Comment: @zkrt please mark my answer correct if it helped! Thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

You are just trying to figure out how to move the files to new directory after you have filtered them, right? Just call `str.replace` on your paths to generate the new path and then pass those strings to `shutil.move`.

```py
import re 
import shutil
import glob

def filter_list(string, substr): 
    return [st for st in string if any(sub in st for sub in substr)] 



#List_1, files in a given directory 
old_path = "/path_to_the_files"
new_path = "/path_to_move_files_to"
list_1=glob.glob(f'{old_path}/*.fa')

#List_2, files that need to be picked
file = open("/path_to_name_list/list_2.txt", "r")
file_lines = file.read()
list_2 = file_lines.split("\n") 


filtered_list=filter_list(list_2,list_1)

for input in filtered_list:
    output = input.replace(old_path, new_path)
    shutil.move(input, output)
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution of moving files but the function in the script doesn't select the files from the given name list. I'm not sure why?